# Google play console alert "detected incorrect implementation"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

Hello i recently created a game with Leaderboard option and i submitted it on google play ..before publishing my game they said i must create 5 achievements so i did that and everything goes well after couple hours i got an alert from google play said "Detected incorrect implementation"

> Your game has incorrectly implemented the following Play Games
>   services: Achievements.

I didn't create my game with this Achievements why they send me this alert how can i fix this problem? is there any risk on my account in google play? can i skip this alert by clicking on ignore?

Comment: It means you have achievements, but no where are you calling the SDK to unlock them. It won't affect your account and yes, you can probably ignore it if you don't care for achievements.

Comment: Alternatively, just add the code to unlock the achievements and make your players feel like they achieved something :)

Comment: @Andy thanks so much now i can rest in peace..

Comment: @ClaytonWilkinson but if i didnt that there is no risk on my account ? this is my first time i have publish a game

Comment: @SteveReck - I am 99.99% sure it is just a warning, not an error, so it should be OK.